# Trouble applying theory to practice

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning, problem-solving, learning

I am a first-year math student and I am having difficulties applying newly learned theory to problems.

For example, my current calculus book is [Real Analysis: Series, Functions of Several Variables, and Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1493973673) which is very theory-heavy. I read the chapters with caution and write down all important definitions and theorems, however when it comes down to solving actual problems (be it the ones in the book or the ones from problem sheets) I am always in a "foggy" state not really knowing what to do.

So my question is how can I apply the theory I learn better? and if you have any good study methods/tricks those will be deeply appreciated as well.

Comment: I mean, this is the core challenge of mathematics? This question is essentially, how do you do math, which is very individual-dependent. For me, I read over a given text as many times as I need to get an idea, go over problems to understand basic applications of the concept, and then read again, focusing on the points I was confused by. Referring to alternate sources also can help, since some texts can be confusing (for me, Hatcher was a pain, even thought it wasn't for some of my classmates).

Comment: Unfortunately, a book that might be right for one person, might not be right for another.  I therefore recommend the arduous path of finding a different book, that is better for you, and seems to cover much the same ground.  Then, when you come to a troublesome chapter in your first book, you can try to conquer the corresponding chapter in the 2nd book, and then come back to the first book.  This is what Don Thousand's "Referring to alternate sources" represents. ...see next comment

Comment: You're not alone!  I would say work problems, problems, problems.  And while you're reading, make sure you ask yourself if you are understanding the material, and then periodically stop and think, "OK, how could this be used?"  Hope that helps.

Comment: Generic tips re finding the right book: [1] You want a book with a **ton** of problems. [2] It helps to check out the Amazon reviews of a book. [3] Try, before you buy: try to find a free pdf of the book you are considering, and try it out.  If it works, then buy the book.  You might have to go through 5 or more authors, before you find the right book.